# kinesis firehose endpoint missing

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have set-up firehose to collect data through agent and push it to elasticasearch. It works for a single record using pyhon code. But I am not able to send data using Kinesis Agent.
As per the documentation, there should be firehose and kinesis endpoints. But there is no such endpoint available.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html

```
{
    "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
    "kinesis.endpoint": "https://your/kinesis/endpoint", 
    "firehose.endpoint": "https://your/firehose/endpoint", 
    "flows": [
        {
            "filePattern": "/tmp/app1.log*", 
            "kinesisStream": "yourkinesisstream"
        }, 
        {
            "filePattern": "/tmp/app2.log*",
            "deliveryStream": "yourfirehosedeliverystream" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

I can not find firehose endpoint. What all I have is the Delivery stream name.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation link you referenced has the value for the Firehose endpoint, but that wouldn't help you for your Kinesis endpoint.

The endpoints depend on the region you're writing to. The default for the Amazon Kinesis Agent is `firehose.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html#agent-config-settings

Your best bet is to refer to the AWS Regions and Endpoints doc:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html